# How to manage list among components in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a `BookingSearch` component.

```js
//imports

@Component({
  selector: 'booking-search',
  templateUrl: './booking-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./booking-search.component.css']
})
export class BookingSearchComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private bookingRetrieveService: BookingRetrieveService,
    private bookingTreeService: BookingTreeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  loadBooking() {

    this.bookingRetrieveService.retrieveBooking(bookingId, firstName, lastName)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          let openBookingUrl = '/booking?b=' + this.bookingId;
          window.open(openBookingUrl, '_self');
        },
        error => { }
      );
  }
}
```

Once the booking is loaded it needs to add into a booking tree and page redireds to `BookingDetail` component.

```js
@Injectable()
export class BookingTreeService {

  constructor() { }

  addBooking(booking) { }
}
```

This booking tree needs to be used in a `BookingDetail` component.

```js
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'booking-detail',
  templateUrl: 'booking-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['booking-detail.component.css']
})

export class BookingDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  booking: any = {};

  constructor(private bookingService: BookingTreeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //how to get updated booking tree here
  }
}
```

How to update booking tree when search new booking and how can it be used in `BookingDetailComponent`.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the booking tree inside a service and access it from your booking-details component.

Like:

```
@Injectable()
export class BookingTreeService {
  bookingTree: Booking[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  addBooking(booking) {
   this.bookingTree.push(booking);
  }
}
```

Then in your bookingDetails component:

```
constructor(private bookingService: BookingTreeService) {
  this.bookings = this.bookingService.bookingTree;
 }
```